# Why do we use the Intersection Observer API? Does it impact speed? Or Give me Some Advantages of using Intersection Observer

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I Want to know why we use the intersection observer API. I want to load my page sections in an interval. Does it affect the page speed or not?

Below is my code. I'm confused why I'm using this when it has no effect on speed or any other things. I have an array of sections and a loader while threshold call.

Please explain to me why we are using this API while it has no advantage

```js
    const featureds = document.querySelectorAll(".featured");
   const options = {
      root: null,
      threshold: 0.25,
      rootMargin: '0px'
    };
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries,observer) {
      entries.forEach(entry => {
         if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
            return;
         }
         console.log(entry);
      });
   }, options);
    featureds.forEach(featured => {
        observer.observe(featured);
    });
```

```html
 <div class="container featured 1">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
         <!-- <h4 class="team-name"></h4> -->
         <h3 class="team-expert"><span>Feature Posts</span></h3>
         <div class="feature-post">
            <div class="container">
               <div class="owl-carousel team-slider nospace group team">
                  <div class="item">
                     <div class="pdf-carousel"> <a class="imgover" href=""> <img src="image/book1.png" alt="Pdf Viewer">
                        <div class="middle">
                           <div class="text">William Shakespeare <br>
                              Edition: <span>1st</span></div>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="item-text">
                           <h4 title="Lorem ipsum doler sit amet">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h4>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                     <div class="pdf-carousel"> <a class="imgover" href=""> <img src="image/book2.jpg" alt="Pdf Viewer">
                        <div class="middle">
                           <div class="text">William Shakespeare <br>
                              Edition: <span>1st</span></div>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="item-text">
                           <h4 title="Lorem ipsum doler sit amet">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h4>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                     <div class="pdf-carousel"> <a class="imgover" href=""> <img src="image/book5.jpg" alt="Pdf Viewer">
                        <div class="middle">
                           <div class="text">William Shakespeare <br>
                              Edition: <span>1st</span></div>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="item-text">
                           <h4 title="Lorem ipsum doler sit amet">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h4>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                     <div class="pdf-carousel"> <a class="imgover" href=""> <img src="image/book3.jpg" alt="Pdf Viewer">
                        <div class="middle">
                           <div class="text">William Shakespeare <br>
                              Edition: <span>1st</span></div>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="item-text">
                           <h4 title="Lorem ipsum doler sit amet">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h4>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                     <div class="pdf-carousel"> <a class="imgover" href=""> <img src="image/book7.jpg" alt="Pdf Viewer">
                        <div class="middle">
                           <div class="text">William Shakespeare <br>
                              Edition: <span>1st</span></div>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="item-text">
                           <h4 title="Lorem ipsum doler sit amet">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h4>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- feature posts ends -->
<!-- popular posts starts -->
<div class="container featured 2">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
         <!-- <h4 class="team-name"></h4> -->
         <h3 class="team-expert"><span>Popular Posts</span></h3>
         <div class="popular-post">
            <div class="container">
               <div class="owl-carousel team-slider nospace group team">
                  <div class="item">
                     <div class="pdf-carousel"> <a class="imgover" href=""> <img src="image/book8.jpg" alt="Pdf Viewer">
                        <div class="middle">
                           <div class="text">William Shakespeare <br>
                              Edition: <span>1st</span></div>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="item-text">
                           <h4 title="Lorem ipsum doler sit amet">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h4>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                     <div class="pdf-carousel"> <a class="imgover" href=""> <img src="image/book2.jpg" alt="Pdf Viewer">
                        <div class="middle">
                           <div class="text">William Shakespeare <br>
                              Edition: <span>1st</span></div>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="item-text">
                           <h4 title="Lorem ipsum doler sit amet">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h4>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                     <div class="pdf-carousel"> <a class="imgover" href=""> <img src="image/book5.jpg" alt="Pdf Viewer">
                        <div class="middle">
                           <div class="text">William Shakespeare <br>
                              Edition: <span>1st</span></div>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="item-text">
                           <h4 title="Lorem ipsum doler sit amet">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h4>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                     <div class="pdf-carousel"> <a class="imgover" href=""> <img src="image/book3.jpg" alt="Pdf Viewer">
                        <div class="middle">
                           <div class="text">William Shakespeare <br>
                              Edition: <span>1st</span></div>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="item-text">
                           <h4 title="Lorem ipsum doler sit amet">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h4>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                     <div class="pdf-carousel"> <a class="imgover" href=""> <img src="image/book7.jpg" alt="Pdf Viewer">
                        <div class="middle">
                           <div class="text">William Shakespeare <br>
                              Edition: <span>1st</span></div>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="item-text">
                           <h4 title="Lorem ipsum doler sit amet">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h4>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"Or Give me Some Advantages of using Intersection Observer"_ - No, because this is not the scope of SO. That's a task for your preferred search provider.

Comment: @Andreas it is different with my last question see the code given it or there...